# Use choices in Jenkins pipeline to define env vars from a nested map

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

What I am trying to achieve is: the user will select an environment and then I can set appropriate env vars for that environment (URL, DB, etc.).
Is it possible?
I tried a lot of things: with interpolation in environment, trying to define environments map in different places but no luck.
My environments map variable is not accesible in environment section and also there seems to be some limitations to what can be done inside environment section, I got messages like:
you can concatenate only with +, env var can only be value or function call.
I tried some variations with those hints but still no luck.

```
def environments = [
  TEST: [APP_URL: 'http://test'],
  DEV: [ APP_URL: 'https://dev'],
  QA: [ APP_URL: 'https://qa']
]

pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    choice(name: 'environment', choices: "${environments.keySet().join('\n')}")
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Test') {
      environment {
        APP_URL = environments[params.environment]['APP_URL']
      }
      steps {
        sh 'env'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works :)

```
def environments = [
  TEST: [APP_URL: 'http://test'],
  DEV: [ APP_URL: 'https://dev'],
  QA: [ APP_URL: 'https://qa']
]

pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    choice(name: 'environment', choices: "${environments.keySet().join('\n')}")
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Test') {
      steps {
        sh """
            export APP_URL=${environments[params.environment]['APP_URL']}
            env
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```